# Why can I not see the JComponent being added to the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcomponent

This sample adds a JButton and a JLabel to a JFrame.

There is also a JComponent that should show the cursor's XY coordinates.

I know there are samples out there showing how to show the XY coordinates but am curious to know why it fails in this scenario.

Looking at the output, it appears that all the required listeners are firing as the output even shows the paintCompoent() getting executed with the expected output.

Not sure if it was required, but I did try to setVisible(true) as well as setBounds().

What is it that is prevents the JComponent with the XY coordinates from appearing.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class XYCoordinateTest extends JFrame 
{

  JLabel label = new JLabel("My Test Label");
  JButton b1 = new JButton("Press Me");
  XYMouseLabel xy = new XYMouseLabel();

  class XYMouseLabel extends JComponent
  {
       public int x;
       public int y;

       public XYMouseLabel() 
       {
         this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
       }

       // use the xy coordinates to update the mouse cursor text/label
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
       {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         String s = x + ", " + y;
         System.out.println("paintComponent() : " + s);
         g.setColor(Color.red);
         g.drawString(s, x, y);
       }
  } 

  public XYCoordinateTest () 
  {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    getContentPane().add(label);
    getContentPane().add(b1);
    xy.setBounds(0, 0,  300, 100);
    xy.setVisible(true);
    getContentPane().add(xy);

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me)
        {
         System.out.println("Panel Mouse Move x : " + me.getX() + "   Y : " + me.getY());
          xy.x = me.getX();
          xy.y = me.getY();
          xy.repaint();
        }
      });
    pack();
    setSize(300, 100);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new XYCoordinateTest().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see you "pack", but the xy component doesn't have a preferred size.

Comment: Just added setPreferredSize and that helped, but I would like it to work for the entire area of the JFrame even over the other 2 components (JLabel and JButton) do I have to do this via a Layered Panel?

Comment: If you're setting bounds on components to be able to place them "above" other components, you might as well use a null layout on the panel. But then you don't get the "flow" of FlowLayout for your label and button. I've never worked with LayeredPane, but from just reading about it a bit I would guess it could work.

Comment: Any idea why the JComponent background was not set to Blue? I thought that would help to show where it sits in the JFrame but the color never appears.

Comment: See [JComponent.setBackground](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)): `Sets the background color of this component. The background color is used only if the component is opaque, and only by subclasses of JComponent or ComponentUI implementations. Direct subclasses of JComponent must override paintComponent to honor this property.

It is up to the look and feel to honor this property, some may choose to ignore it.`

Comment: Thanks. I guess dealing directly with the JComponent has introduced some pitfalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xy component doesn't have a preferred size. You call [pack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) on the JFrame, which sizes components to their preferred sizes. Since the xy component doesn't have one, it becomes invisible.

Comment: Neither the JButton nor the JLabel have a preferred size? Does the constructor of these objects set one?

Comment: They do have a preferred size; it is implemented by the JLabel and JButton classes, to take account the text size, border size, etc. You in your component have not provided an override for "getPreferredSize" which by default returns new Size(0,0) (I have not checked the implementation of JComponent though, it's an educated guess).

Comment: You're welcome @UnhandledException :-) Happy coding!